# Azure Site Recovery Replication - Not able to select existing destination key vault for disk encryption

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, azure-site-recovery

I am trying to setup ASR replication (Azure to Azure) for ADE encrypted Azure VM (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter) referencing MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-how-to-enable-replication-ade-vms

As per the documentation we can customize "*Target disk encryption key vault*" but the existing key vault in the target resource group is not populating in the list to select. I have verified my access on the target keyvault as mentioned in the documentation.

[customize target key vault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWRct.png)

I am able to customize other targets like resource group, vnet, cache storage account availability set; issue seems with the key vault only.

[review targets for replication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz39Y.png)

Comment: Is your Key Vault in the same region as your target? That may be the issue why you on't see your KV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The target location is where your source virtual machine data will be
> replicated. Site Recovery provides a list of suitable target regions
> based on the selected machine's location. We recommend that you use
> the same location as the Recovery Services vault's location

As suggested by *@piotr.gradzinksi* make sure to have Key Vault in the same region as your target.

Try to replicate a virtual machine that has key vault on a source region.

Ensure you have all the **permissions** on the source region key vault.

I’m getting the results by following the same document that you have mentioned.

This may be the issue with virtual machine which you are creating is in **different** resource group region compared to key vault. If still getting the same issue I would suggest you follow the same document to confirm which region your resource group is in.